# Mockito with Junit for Spring

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-webflux

I am new to mockito, I need to write a JUnit test case for my project for both success and failure scenarios. I have 2 issues. First, in Mockito when I am using `service.addSeasons()` it is always giving as null. How should I get the response to make it assert? Second, what should I do to test failure with test exception as well? I am doing it like below but not sure whether it is correct or not. I am using `jupiter.api.Test` to run these.

Actual code :

```java
public Mono<SuccessResponse> addSeason(String uuid, HuntsDetailSeasonsDto huntsDetailSeasonsDto) {
  Flux<Hunter> hm = a.findByUuidAndIsPrimaryAndDeleted(uuid, true, false);
  return hm.next().flatMap(h -> {
    huntsDetailSeasonsDto.setHunterId(h.getId());
    Mono<HuntsDetail> hsm = b.findByIdAndDeleted(huntsDetailSeasonsDto.getHuntId(), false);
    return hsm.flatMap(hsm1 -> {
      return b
          .save(c.createAddSeasonsEntity(huntsDetailSeasonsDto, hsm1)).map(l -> {
            SuccessResponse resp = new SuccessResponse();
            return resp;
          });
    }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BusinessException()));
  }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BusinessException()));
}
```

Mockito test case

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest
public class TestHuntsSeasonsService {

    @InjectMocks
    CLassAService service;

    @MockBean
    B b;

    @MockBean
    C c;

    @MockBean
    A a;

    @MockBean
    AppProperties properties;

    @MockBean
    SeasonsAdapter seasonsAdapter;

    @Test
    public void addSeasonTest() {
        HuntsDetailSeasonsDto dto = new HuntsDetailSeasonsDto();
        dto.setHunterId(1802L);
        dto.setHuntId(7L);
        dto.setSeasonsRef(24140L);

        HuntsDetail huntsDetail = new HuntsDetail();
        huntsDetail.setHunterId(1802L);
        huntsDetail.setHuntCollectionId("7");
        huntsDetail.setSeasonsDtl("24140");
        Mockito.when(a.findByUuidAndIsPrimaryAndDeleted(CommonUtilTest.LOGGEDINUSER,
            true, false)).thenReturn(CommonUtilTest.hunterFlux());
        Mockito.when(b.findByIdAndDeleted(dto.getHuntId(), false))
            .thenReturn(CommonUtilTest.huntsDetailMono());
        Mockito.when(c.createAddSeasonsEntity(dto, CommonUtilTest.huntsDetail()))
            .thenReturn(CommonUtilTest.huntsDetail());
        Mockito.when(repository.save(huntsDetail)).thenReturn(Mono.just(huntsDetail));
        service.addSeason(CommonUtilTest.LOGGEDINUSER, dto);
          
        Mockito.verify(service, times(1)).addSeason(CommonUtilTest.LOGGEDINUSER, dto);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error? Your question header does not state a question, and the only sort of question is ”im mot sure if its correct or not” that is an opinion, and questions that result in opinions are not allowed on stack overflow according to the rules.

Comment: @Toerktumlare question _titles_ don't need to be in the form of an interrogative, though it is recommended. The question _body_, which one should also read, does contain two questions: "*How should I get the response to make it assert? Second, what should I do to test failure with test exception as well?*"

Comment: no one is subscribing to the `Mono` returned by `service.addSeason` which means your reactive stream will never run. [StepVerifier](https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher) is a great testing tool for reactor code.